# Has anyone been able to get FB.Canvas.setUrlHandler to work?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

Even using the default test code on my app I can't get this working. It performs a whole page refresh when going into the app via a request notification even if my callback is just a log to see if it fired.

```
FB.Canvas.setUrlHandler(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The docs lead me to believe that this should not cause the iframed page to lose its state... but for the life of me I can't get it working.

Relevant Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setUrlHandler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, this function seems to be no longer working for some reason.

We've been using it in our facebook app successfully and it suddenly stopped working without us having touched the code.

EDIT: Bug is logged here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/175498382567165

Please help get it fixed sooner by marking it as reproduced by you and add some info.